# Light passing through paper (Chinese Lantern)

Tags: rendering, shaders, lighting

I am beginner of blender. I try to render a Chinese lantern and it is my reference.

[image]

I do some research on google and found that most of the people use Mix Shader(Translucent and Diffuse). So it is my first try.

[image]

It looks bad. The whole lantern is a same color. So I adjust the Transmission value.
[image]

It looks better but not enough.  Theses parts have no difference of brightness. I try to scale down the light source. It worse.

[image]

The problem is not fix and two strange glow edge appear. I guess they are the shape of my model.

[image]

I have no ideas how to fix those problems. Please give me some suggestions

Comment: I think increasing the Subsurface Scattering a tiny bit may help, you could try that

Comment: Are you working in Eevee? Translucency doesn't seem to work as good as in Cycles... Take a look at the second answer here, he talks about switching the Principled from CGX to Multiscatter CGX

Answer (score 7):

Here is a quick take using Cycles.

Bottom line here, some Transmission and Transmission Roughness and a pinch of Subsurface scattering.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nicely done, and nicely shown. I wonder what your kanji mean?

Comment: The Chinese name I was given :)